# How can I deploy an ingress controller for my Kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

So I built my Kubernetes cluster on AWS using [KOPS](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md)

I then deployed SocketCluster on my K8s cluster using [Baasil](https://docs.baasil.io/deploying_your_app_to_your_kubernetes_cluster.html) which deploys 7 [YAML files](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/tree/master/kubernetes)

My problem is: the [scc-ingress](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/blob/master/kubernetes/scc-ingress.yaml) isn't getting any IP or endpoint as I have not deployed any [ingress controller](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#ingress-controllers).

According to [ingress controller](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#ingress-controllers) docs, I am recommended to deploy an [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/README.md)

I need easy and explained steps to deploy the nginx ingress controller for my specific cluster.

To view the current status of my cluster in a nice GUI, see the screenshots below:

**Deployments**

[image: Deployments]

**Ingress**

[image: Ingress]

**Pods**

[image: Pods]

**Replica Sets**

[image: Replica Sets]

**Services**

[image: Services]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is here https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/ingress-nginx

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kops/master/addons/ingress-nginx/v1.4.0.yaml

But obviously the scc-ingress file needed to be changed to have a host such as foo.bar.com

Also, need to generate a self-signed SSL using OpenSSL as per this link https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/tls

Finally, had to add a CNAME on Route53 from foo.bar.com to the dns of the ELB created

Comment: I am trying to deploy socketcluster with scc-broker and scc-state locally on `minikube`. But I am facing the similar issue not able to get any external endpoints exposed on ingress. do I need to deploy ingress controller to make things work. And is yes Could you please provide me a link of proper documentation for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Dv_MH this didn't work. I know it was a couple of years ago, but can you provide any insight into how you got the `scc-ingress` working?